# Make form allow minimum number 10 or higher to be inputted

Tags: php

I have a form on my site, and I want to make the minimum number that's allowed to be inputted be 10 or higher.

Here's the code for that form:

```
<input type="number" id="amount" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" class="form-control" value="10" placeholder="1.00" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Can anyone help me get this done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `value` to `min`

```
<input type="number" id="amount" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" class="form-control" min="10" placeholder="1.00" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Comment: That worked. I actually added that in addition to the value. So when that form loads the number 10 is already inputted, and people can't use the scroll to scroll below 10. However, if someone inputs a smaller number manually, they can still do it. Can I also prevent that somehow?

Comment: Also values that are minus can be inputted manually. (ex. -100). Can I somehow prevent anything below 10 from being inputted in that form completely?

Comment: Use javascript to detect the change and if it's less than the min, set it to 10

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Could you tell me how? I'll google it and try to get it done. But if you can tell me how to do that I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this question has the PHP tag. in first place you need to consider Jaime's answer for client side (and please add a name attribute for any form input. in this case we assume you set the name to "amount"), and at back-end PHP do this :

```
<?php
$error = '';
$amount = ''; // default value;

if (isset($_REQUEST['amount'])) {
    $amount = intval($_REQUEST['amount']); // get the value as number
    if ($amount < 10) $error = 'the amount is under 10 and not acceptable';
}
echo $error;
?>
```